# Get network operator name in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am looking to get the name of the operator for the user's Android device.

E.g. "Verizon" or "Vodafone", I think I have found the Android equivalent documented here called getSimOperatorName() from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkOperatorName()

I am scanning over the documentation for Appcelerator Titanium, but can't seem to find a way of doing this in the docs (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network).

Is this possible in Appcelerator Titanium?

Comment: @fokke-appcelerator Is there any way to do this in iOS? For android I see the solution is discussed in accepted answer but I wasn't able to find any solution for iOS. Thanks.

Comment: We don't expose it in core and I don't know of a module, but it would need to use [TCCarrier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCarrier/carrierName). Would make a good feature request to have this in core for both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get tinetworkinfo Module working. However, a module named [TelephonyManager](http://gitt.io/component/com.goyya.telephonymanager) worked fine.

I ran this in the terminal for the project:

gittio install com.goyya.telephonymanager

Then this code to get the network operator name:

```
var telephonymanager = require("com.goyya.telephonymanager");
Ti.API.log('networkOperatorName:   ' + telephonymanager.networkOperatorName);
```

Comment: what about iOS? Did you ever find out?

Comment: its too old , i can't find new module !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tinetworkinfo](http://gitt.io/component/com.clever_apps.tinetworkinfo) Module

Ex:-

```
var netInfo = require('com.clever_apps.tinetworkinfo');

var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({exitOnClose: true});

var testLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    height:"80%",
    width:"90%",
    top:0
});

var refreshButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:"Refresh Data",
    height:"15%",
    bottom:"5%"
});
refreshButton.addEventListener("click", getTelephonyData);

win.add(testLabel);
win.add(refreshButton);
getTelephonyData();
win.open();


function getTelephonyData(){
    var imei = netInfo.getIMEI();
    var cellid = netInfo.getCellID();
    var lac = netInfo.getLac();
    var mnc = netInfo.getMNC();
    var mmc = netInfo.getMMC();


    var outString = "IMEI: "+imei+"\nCell ID: "+cellid+"\nLAC: "+lac+"\nMNC: "+mnc+"\nMMC: "+mmc;
    testLabel.text = outString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, have you got this working before? I have tried installing the module and running my application and I get an error stating "art: No implementation found for void com.clever_apps.tinetworkinfo.TinetworkinfoBootstrap.nativeBootstrap() (tried Java_com_clever_1apps_tinetworkinfo_TinetworkinfoBootstrap_nativeBootstrap and Java_com_clever_1apps_tinetworkinfo_TinetworkinfoBootstrap_nativeBootstrap__)", I installed it using the command "gittio install com.clever_apps.tinetworkinfo"

Comment: u found any new module yet ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no API that will return you that information. For that, you need to create your own Android module.