# Can I view cell-id/lac information with Titanium appcelerator?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, cellid

Can I view cell-id/lac information with Titanium?
Please provide answers for both iphone & android.
Any module please provide with link if possible,

Many Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get network operator name in Appcelerator Titanium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708100/get-network-operator-name-in-appcelerator-titanium)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708100/get-network-operator-name-in-appcelerator-titanium